# Отображение BLOB в Vaadin Grid

Tags: java, jpa, vaadin

Приветствую!
Ситуация такая - есть БД Оракл, в нем таблица Worker, в ней фото рабочих в формате BLOB. Неофходимо отобразить в Vaadin Grid вместе с остальными данными.

Как сейчас работает: в классе @Entity для Worker поле foto выдергивается как byte[], из него приходится отдельно сохранять на жеский диск, а в грид подсовывать new ThemeResource(PATH) в ImageRenderer().

Есть ли возможность напрямую передовать картинку без сохранения на жеский диск?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create the stream resource with some initial filename
StreamResource imageResource = new StreamResource(imageSource, "initial-filename.png");

// Instruct browser not to cache the image
imageResource.setCacheTime(0);

// Display the image
Image image = new Image(null, imageResource);
```

Более подробно о [Resources](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-embedded.html) и о [StreamResources](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-resources.html#application.resources.stream) в Vaadin

Answer (score 0):

Лучшим решением будет перенос картинок из базы на front-end сервер и сохранение в базе только ссылок.

ЗЫ Хранение графических данных в blob полях - то еще извращение)) 
Извини, если не помог.

Comment: Сейчас примерно так и работает:)

Comment: Проблема в том - есть несколько сторонних баз, и есть приложение Vaadin, которое к ним подключается. Для отображения приходиться на ходу их сохранять на диск, после этого отображать. Хранить их нет смысла.

Comment: Я Vaadin не знаю, но на низком уровне проще тогда не на диск сохранять, а размапить такие img в аплет (в фильтр) и в request отдавать. По крайней мере экономия времени работы с диском. Я так думаю, что Vorh примерно это и предложил)